# Issue with installing lispbuilder-SDL on Linux. - "Don't know how to require ASDF-INSTALL"

Tags: linux, sdl, common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I am trying to install  lispbuilder-SDL on Linux using the instructions given [here.](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/DownloadInstallation) I have gotten to the part where I must install CFFI using ASDF but I am getting the following error when I try to  type (require 'asdf-install):

Don't know how to REQUIRE ASDF-INSTALL. [Condition of type SB-INT:EXTENSION-FAILURE]

What do you suggest I do next? I tried looking it up but I found nothing helpful and I am new to all of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Direct quote from the [ASDF-INSTALL web page](http://www.cliki.net/asdf-install):

"ASDF-install is OBSOLETE. DO NOT USE ASDF-INSTALL, EVER. DO NOT ASK AROUND ABOUT HOW TO GET IT RUNNING. IT IS O-B-S-O-L-E-T-E. Not working. Not maintained. Please use quicklisp instead."

So, you should use [quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org) instead.

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "cffi")
To load "cffi":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cffi
; Loading "cffi"

("cffi")
CL-USER>
```

Comment: Also, `(ql:system-apropos "lispbuilder")`, find what you need, then `(ql:quickload "lispbuilder-sdl")`.